# Adding a new line in between in an array in VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

How do I enter a blank row in between an array in VBA? In the code below, I am copying the whole data into array and then checking if any two values in column D as different or not. If they are, then enter a blank row. The code which I am using:

```
sub enternewline()

Dim Start, Finish, TotalTime
Dim WorksheetToRead As String
Dim DataRange As String
Dim SheetArray As Variant


'Start = Timer

   WorksheetToRead = "sht_mccr"
    StartCol = "D"
    EndCol = "F"
    StartRow = 4
    lastrow = 80000 'Sheets(WorksheetToRead).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

  DataRange = StartCol & Trim(Str(StartRow)) & ":" & EndCol & Trim(Str(StartRow - 1 + lastrow))

  SheetArray = sht_mccr.Range(DataRange).Value

    For ArrayLoopCounter = LBound(SheetArray, 1) To UBound(SheetArray, 1)
      If SheetArray(ArrayLoopCounter, 1) <> SheetArray(ArrayLoopCounter + 1, 1) Or _
         SheetArray(ArrayLoopCounter, 2) <> SheetArray(ArrayLoopCounter + 1, 2) Then

    SheetArray(ArrayLoopCounter, 1) = ""
    SheetArray(ArrayLoopCounter + 1, 1).EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown  //Wanted help here in this line as to how to enter a new blank line in an array
.
.
.
.
end sub()
```

Comment: Just add a carriage return to the string.

Comment: Can you explain a bit as I'm new in this field. Please help.

Comment: I have the knowledge to explain more in depth but I don't believe it would serve the community to do so.  I wish you luck

Comment: That's very generous. Thank you.

Comment: Why do you need to insert "rows"?  What are you doing with the data once you have "inserted" the row?  (There are workarounds that you could use, but the best method will depend a lot on what you are doing.)